# Pin doesn't toggle in CTC mode

Tags: c, timer, avr

I'm trying to toggle OC1A pin (PB1) in CTC mode with given frequency. But PB1 doesn't toggle. If i trying to toggle pin using interruptions everything works fine, but for my project it is necessary to make it without interrupt. Maybe I missed something?

I'm using Arduino Nano on Atmega328P. According to datasheet:

> Table 15-2. Compare Output Mode, non-PWM
>
> COM1A1/COM1B1 COM1A0/COM1B0 Description
>
> 0 0 Normal port operation, OC1A/OC1B disconnected.
>
> 0 1 Toggle OC1A/OC1B on compare match.
>
> 1 0 Clear OC1A/OC1B on compare match (set output to low level).
>
> 1 1 Set OC1A/OC1B on compare match (set output to high level).

If I'm right, it is possible to set COM1A0 bit and OC1A will toggle when TCNT1 will reach the TOP value. But in my code it doesn't work:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
  DDRB |= (1<<PB1);
  PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1); 
  TCCR1B |= (1<<CS11)|(1<<WGM12); //prescaler 8 CTC mode with TOP on OCR1A
  TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1A0); //toggle PB1
  TCNT1 = 0;
  OCR1A = 30000;
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

If I'm using interrupt port is toggling, but changing of OCR1A has no effect on frequency.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
  DDRB |= (1<<PB1);
  PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1); 
  TCCR1B |= (1<<CS11)|(1<<WGM12); //prescaler 8 CTC mode with TOP on OCR1A
  TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1A0); //toggle PB1
  TCNT1 = 0;
  OCR1A = 30000;
  TIMSK1 |= (1<<OCIE1A);
}

void loop() {
  
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  PINB = (1<<PB1);
}
```

Is it possible to toggle OC1A while using OCR1A as TOP in CTC? Or I must use WGM13:0=12 and ICR1 as TOP?

Comment: It looks like you're only setting/clearing some of the bits that control the timer's operation, and relying on the defaults for the rest. Are you sure the defaults are what you expect/need them to be? If you explicitly set/clear all of the control register bits, do you have any better luck?

Comment: Joseph, thank you for your comment! Default value of bits is zero, so everything must be ok i think. Still, i will try to change not the certain bits, but register at all. Thank you one more time!

Comment: Probably Arduino IDE put some other initialization code on timer1 between `setup()` and `loop()`. Try move the code into `loop()` and add empty cycle (e.g. `for (;;) {}`) at the end of it

Comment: Ok, now everything works fine. Joseph Sible was right: I shouldn't rely on default values in register. I simply zeroized TCCR1A and TCCR1B and replaced "|=" with "=". Now Everything works fine! Thank you! Can I mark somehow your comment like right answer?
AterLux, thank you. It was my mistake that I didn't marked that I'm using VS Studio Code. Any way, thank you too!

Comment: I added an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're assuming that the value of all the bits in those registers that you're not setting is 0. The Arduino code uses the timers for its own purposes, so this isn't a good assumption. You should set/clear all of the bits that you care about the value of.

Answer (score -1):

you forgot to set the global interrupt flag called sei().
Your code prepares everything but the global interrupt flag is not set. 
In void setup() add sei() to enable it, and cli() to disable the global interrupt flags.

Comment: The Arduino already has interrupts enabled when the sketch starts, and nothing in that sketch is disabling them again.